# how to grab the value from the radiobutton to make a if statement

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from ProjectHeader import *


class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.gui = parent

        self.gui.geometry("350x200")

        self.gui.title("Converter")

        self.checked1 = IntVar()
        self.checked2 = IntVar()

        self.c1 = Radiobutton(self.gui, text='(1)Centimeters', variable=self.checked1, value = 1)
        self.c2 = Radiobutton(self.gui, text='(2)Meter', variable=self.checked1, value = 2)
        self.c3 = Radiobutton(self.gui, text='(3)Millimeters', variable=self.checked1, value = 3)
        self.c4 = Radiobutton(self.gui, text='(4)Kilometers', variable=self.checked1, value = 4)

        self.c5 = Radiobutton(self.gui, text='(5)Centimeters', variable=self.checked2, value = 5)
        self.c6 = Radiobutton(self.gui, text='(6)Meter', variable=self.checked2, value = 6)
        self.c7 = Radiobutton(self.gui, text='(7)Millimeters', variable=self.checked2, value = 7)
        self.c8 = Radiobutton(self.gui, text='(8)Kilometers', variable=self.checked2, value = 8)

        self.b1 = Button(self.gui, text="Convert", command=self.callback)
        self.l1 = Label(self.gui, text="Value")
        self.l2 = Label(self.gui, text="Convert ->")
        self.e1 = Entry(self.gui, bd = 5)

        self.e1.insert(0, "0")

        self.c1.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        self.c2.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        self.c3.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        self.c4.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        self.c5.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        self.c6.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        self.c7.pack(side = BOTTOM)
        self.c8.pack(side = BOTTOM)

        self.l1.pack(side = TOP)
        self.l2.pack(side = TOP)
        self.e1.pack(side = TOP)
        self.b1.pack(side = TOP)

        self.c1.place(x = 3, y = 90)
        self.c2.place(x = 3, y = 110)
        self.c3.place(x = 3, y = 130)
        self.c4.place(x = 3, y = 150)
        self.c5.place(x = 235, y = 90)
        self.c6.place(x = 235, y = 110)
        self.c7.place(x = 235, y = 130)
        self.c8.place(x = 235, y = 150)

        self.l2.place(x = 140, y = 110)



    def callback(self):


        if self.e1.get() == "0":
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please enter a value")

        elif self.checked1.get(): #Centiemters
            C = Centimeters(self.e1.get())
            if self.checked2.get():
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Converting the same unit!")
            if self.checked2.get():
                value = C.ToMeters()
                messagebox.showinfo("Value", str(value) + ' cm')
            if self.checked2.get():
                value = C.ToMillimeters()
                messagebox.showinfo("Value", str(value) + ' cm')
            if self.checked2.get():
                value = C.ToKilometers()
                messagebox.showinfo("Value", str(value) + ' cm')

root = Tk()

my_window = Gui(root)

root.mainloop()
```

so now I changed the `self.checked1.get() == 1` to `self.checked1.get()`
because you said by checking on the radiobutton, it would select the option

but now, when I the check the (1)Centimeters button, or either (5)Centimeters to (8)Kilometers button, the program would select all the options

for example, if I checked (1)Centimeters button and (8)Kilometers, the program would pop up not only converted value of Kilometers, but also the converted value of meters, millimeters.

so my question is how can I fix the program that when I checked the 1st box on the left side, and either one of the boxes on the right side, the program would give the correct selection?

Here is the interface of checkedbutton
http://postimg.org/image/6uqwkybw5/

Comment: The if statements seem to be working quite good, except for that you should compare `self.checked2.get()` to 5, 6, 7 and 8 for the converting and the error `Converting to the same unit`, because `self.checked1` can only be 1, 2, 3 or 4. What exactly is the problem you experience and what is your question?

Comment: yes, so you see there have value 1 - 8, is it possible to use those value in my if statement? thank you for reply

Comment: You **are** using them in your if-statement. But `self.checked1` can be 1-4, `self.checked2` can be 5-8. So `self.checked1.get() == 5` always returns False.

Comment: so how can I determine to 1? like, self.check1.get().1   ?

Comment: Determine to 1? I really don't know what you mean. The `IntVar` `self.checked1` is 1-4 depending on which of the four left radio buttons is clicked. `self.checked2` is 5-8 depending on the right radiobuttons. By using the `.get()` method you can retreive the value of the `IntVar`s. If you need any more help than that, you're going to have to ask a clearer and more concrete question.

Comment: Sorry for I didn't ask clearly, and I think I got what you mean. And I changed my code

Comment: I don't think you really got what i mean. `self.checked2.get()` returns 5, 6, 7 or 8, depending on which of the right radiobuttons is checked. What you have to do now is compare `self.checked2.get()` with these numbers using `==`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you should use the following code. Use `self.checked1.get()` to see what is the original unit and use `self.checked2.get()` to see to which unit it has to be converted.

```
    if self.e1.get() == "0":
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Please enter a value")

    elif self.checked1.get() == 1: #Centimeters
        C = Centimeters(self.e1.get())
        if self.checked2.get() == 5:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Converting the same unit!")
        if self.checked2.get() == 6:
            value = C.ToMeters()
            messagebox.showinfo("Value", str(value) + ' m')
        if self.checked2.get() == 7:
            value = C.ToMillimeters()
            messagebox.showinfo("Value", str(value) + ' mm')
        if self.checked2.get() == 8:
            value = C.ToKilometers()
            messagebox.showinfo("Value", str(value) + ' km')
```

Comment: Oh I got it, so I did wrong in my comparison.  Ok, thank you :D

Comment: Glad to hear that. If this answer helped you out in finding the solution, you can let the community know by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as described in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).